# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void Car.setYear(java.lang.Integer)'

Tags: java

[image][image]I am writing this code for a class and it is asking me for the following problem statement:
Problem Statement
**Design a class named Car that has the following fields:**

**year**: The year field is an integer that holds the car’s year.

**make**: the make field is a String that holds the make of the car.

**speed**: the speed field is an integer that holds the car’s current speed.

In addition, the class should have the following constructor and other methods:

**Constructor**: the constructor should accept the car’s year >model and make as parameters. These values should be assigned to the object’s yearand make fields. The constructor should also assign 0 to the speed field.

**Accessors**: design appropriate accessor methods to get the values stored in an object’s year, make, and speed fields.

I am receiving the error message. "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void Car.setYear(java.lang.Integer)'
at Mod10MyCar.main(Mod10MyCar.java:21)"

Is anyone able to help me out here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mod10MyCar {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Declare input variables
    Integer inputYear;
    String inputMake;
    Integer inputSpeed;

    // Create a Car object
    Car Type = new Car();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // get values of a car
    System.out.println("What is the year of the car?");
    inputYear = keyboard.nextInt();
    Type.setYear(inputYear);

    System.out.println("What is the make of the car?");
    inputMake = keyboard.nextLine();
    Type.setMake(inputMake);

    //Show values of car
    System.out.println("The car year is " + Type.getYear());
      System.out.println("The make is " + Type.getMake());

}
}

class Car {

// Fields
String make;
Integer year;
Integer speed;

// Constructor
public void Car(String make, Integer year) {

    this.year = year;
    this.make = make;
    this.speed = 0;
}

// Mutators
public void setYear(Integer year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public void setMake(String make) {
    this.make = make;
}

public void setSpeed(Integer speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

// Accessors
public String getMake() {
    return make;
}

public Integer getYear() {
    return year;
}

public Integer getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try recompiling?

Comment: still receiving the same error.

Comment: I have copied and pasted your code and i do not see any errors, are you sure you are running the correct file??

Comment: Also don't use `Integer`. Use `int` instead.

Comment: I am running in VS Code on a Mac. I press either the debug or run button at the top. Program asks for the year of the car. I enter the year and then it throws the error message I posted. To me, that means my code is working up until line 21 where "Type.setYear(inputYear);" is.

Comment: Try changing all `Integer` to `int` as i mentioned.

Comment: I changed all "Integer" to "int" same error. :/

Comment: can you post a screen shot?

Comment: I do not think I can post a screenshot in the comments. Is there somewhere else I can do that?

Comment: yes, edit your question

Comment: Included a screenshot

Comment: Can you show me the class Car as well because i do not see anything wrong here.

Comment: I cannot read your screen shots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are following issues with your code:

1. default Constructor is missing
2. parameterised constructor is void type, which is wrong. Ideally, constructors have no return type
3. Car Type = new Car(); since there is no default constructor, this call makes no sense.

Use the following code :

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mod10MyCar {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Declare input variables
    int inputYear;
    String inputMake;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // get values of a car
    System.out.println("What is the year of the car?");
    inputYear = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the make of the car?");
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    inputMake = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    Car Type = new Car(inputMake, inputYear);

    //Show values of car
    System.out.println("The car year is " + Type.getYear());
      System.out.println("The make is " + Type.getMake());
      System.out.println("Speed :" + Type.getSpeed());

}
}

class Car {

// Fields
String make;
int year;
int speed;

Car() {}

// Constructor
public Car(String make, Integer year) {
    this.year = year;
    this.make = make;
}

// Mutators
public void setYear(Integer year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public void setMake(String make) {
    this.make = make;
}

public void setSpeed(Integer speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

// Accessors
public String getMake() {
    return make;
}

public Integer getYear() {
    return year;
}

public Integer getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not know the IDE that you are using but from this I can assume that you are only compiling the `Mod10MyCar` class and not `Car` as you would want to. I don't know how it works on this IDE but try compiling both. Or make two different `.java` so you are sure when you compile the whole project will be compiled.

[image]

Also for java i would reccomend Intellij IDE. It is free for students.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. First of all, I want to thank each and every one of you for taking the time to help me. It appears that something weird was going on with how I saved the .java file.

I basically created a whole new .java file named myCar3.java and copied all of the source code and pasted it in the new file also changing the public class name to match it. This fixed whatever weird issue was going on.

To add to the weirdness, I reopened the Mod10MyCar.java file (the one I posted) and the error went away. Seems like it was most likely the IDE that was "glitching". Consider this a issue with the IDE and not the source code.

Thank you all again.